# How do you aggregate attribute table data at LSOA level to MSOA level?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, population

I have population data stored at the LSOA (Lower layer Super Output Area) but I want to aggregate the data into MSOA (Middle layer Super Output Area). I have the shapefiles for both LSOA and MSOA - each MSOA is broken into 3-5 LSOAs. I have a feeling I need to use "Join attributes by location" but after trying this the population totals for all MSOAs compared to all LSOAs does not add up.

Answer (score 2):

You need the [Output Area to Lower Layer Super Output Area to Middle Layer Super Output Area to Local Authority District (December 2011) Lookup in England and Wales lookup table](https://ons.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=baf6566ca08949c6bbd61ff81d9526da).

```
OA11CD,LSOA11CD,LSOA11NM,MSOA11CD,MSOA11NM,LAD11CD,LAD11NM,LAD11NMW
E00000001,E01000001,City of London 001A,E02000001,City of London 001,E09000001,City of London,
E00000003,E01000001,City of London 001A,E02000001,City of London 001,E09000001,City of London,
E00000005,E01000001,City of London 001A,E02000001,City of London 001,E09000001,City of London,
E00000007,E01000001,City of London 001A,E02000001,City of London 001,E09000001,City of London,
E00000010,E01000003,City of London 001C,E02000001,City of London 001,E09000001,City of London,
E00000012,E01000003,City of London 001C,E02000001,City of London 001,E09000001,City of London,
E00000013,E01000003,City of London 001C,E02000001,City of London 001,E09000001,City of London,
E00000014,E01000003,City of London 001C,E02000001,City of London 001,E09000001,City of London,
```

The equivelant Scottish table is [available](https://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/files//geography/2011-census-indexes-csv.zip) from the NRS.

```
OutputArea2011Code,LAU2011Level2Code,Islands2011Code,Settlement2010Code,Locality2010Code,CouncilArea2011Code,LocalCharacteristicSector2011Code,DetailedCharacteristicSector2011Code,PostcodeSector2011,HealthBoardArea2006Code,CivilParish1930Code,NationalPark2010Code,StrategicDevelopmentPlanningArea2008Code,CommunityHealthPartnership2012Code,CommunityHealthPartnershipSubAreas2011Code,EnterpriseRegion2008Code,ScottishParliamentaryRegion1999Code,UKParliamentaryConstituency2005Code,ScottishParliamentaryConstituency1999Code,ScottishParliamentaryRegion2011Code,ScottishParliamentaryConstituency2011Code,ElectoralWard2007Code,Datazone2001Code,IntermediateZone2001Code,ScottishIndexofMultipleDeprivation2012Code,UrbanRural8Fold2011_12Code,UrbanRural6Fold2011_12Code,OutputArea2001Code,OutputArea1991Code,MasterPostcode,Easting,Northing,Hectarage,SquareKilometres
S00093944,S31000001,,S20000477,S19000597,S12000041,S29000146,S28000134,DD8 4,S08000013,522,,S11000002,S03000038,S26000035,S09000005,S17000005,S14000004,S16000059,S17000014,S16000082,S13002508,S01000675,S02000123,5846,3,3,S00004507,6451AK07D,DD8 4TU,338436,755296,21.437304,0.214373
S00132898,S31000378,,S20000110,S19000133,S12000030,S29000375,S28000333,FK8 3,S08000005,470,,,S03000011,S26000011,S09000002,S17000005,S14000057,S16000068,S17000013,S16000144,S13002807,S01006149,S02001179,4282,6,5,S00040457,5707AL17B,FK8 3PT,266332,699954,7.328627,0.073286
S00095247,S31000216,,S20000349,S19000379,S12000026,S29001001,S28000856,TD6 0,S08000002,766,,S11000003,S03000004,S26000004,S09000004,S17000007,S14000008,S16000066,S17000015,S16000111,S13002769,S01005406,S02001031,4006,6,5,S00005737,5602AP07B,TD6 0BS,359832,631042,2.89751,0.028975
S00119131,S31001050,,S20000286,S19000315,S12000017,S29000745,S28000652,KW9 6,S08000008,157,,,S03000044,S26000025,S09000003,S17000003,S14000009,S16000009,S17000011,S16000086,S13002666,S01003962,S02000762,2517,8,6,S00027843,6127AF04B,KW9 6QZ,290394,904561,29.994088,0.299941
S00097920,S31000496,,S20000309,S19000338,S12000006,S29000165,S28000152,DG2 7,S08000003,829,,,S03000005,S26000005,S09000004,S17000007,S14000013,S16000019,S17000015,S16000114,S13002538,S01001005,S02000185,5691,2,2,S00008211,5809AE14C,DG2 7NX,296162,575723,4.850901,0.048509
S00095782,S31000223,,S20000447,S19000485,S12000026,S29000986,S28000843,TD1 1,S08000002,339,,S11000003,S03000004,S26000004,S09000004,S17000007,S14000008,S16000070,S17000015,S16000131,S13002763,S01005441,S02001038,2916,2,2,S00006223,5602AE18,TD1 1TB,347111,637620,4.335515,0.043355
S00120583,S31000184,,S20000461,S19000546,S12000019,S29000220,S28000203,EH18 1,S08000010,536,,S11000003,S03000032,S26000031,S09000002,S17000004,S14000045,S16000055,S17000012,S16000130,S13002691,S01004183,S02000800,3991,2,2,S00029197,6230AD01,EH18 1JR,329103,664863,10.279965,0.1028
S00097516,S31000471,,S20000298,S19000327,S12000006,S29000183,S28000170,DG9 8,S08000003,699,,,S03000005,S26000005,S09000004,S17000007,S14000013,S16000035,S17000015,S16000114,S13002532,S01000915,S02000172,3426,6,5,S00007822,5811AJ02C,DG9 8LB,200335,554513,7.364213,0.073642
S00119061,S31001029,,S20000234,S19000263,S12000017,S29000648,S28000566,IV6 7,S08000008,846,,,S03000044,S26000024,S09000003,S17000003,S14000055,S16000065,S17000011,S16000143,S13002670,S01003870,S02000747,4388,6,5,S00027793,6125AC02C,IV6 7TL,252450,849949,42.512724,0.425127
```